# Edit IIS 7 Bindings in ASP.NET VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

How can I add new bindings to an IIS 7.5 site in code using VB ASP.NET please?
I don't need to edit, enumerate or delete the bindings, just add a new one.

I would like to add www.bobspasta.com on IP 88.11.23.12 to site PASTASITEDOTNET4
(fictional data)

Thank you for your help.

MassiveGeek

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do that in VB.NET

Dim IIS As ServerManager, szSite As Site, strBind As String
strBind = "www.bobspasta.com"

IIS = New ServerManager()
szSite = IIS.Sites("PASTASITEDOTNET4")
szSite.Bindings.Add("*:80:" & strBind, "http")

IIS.CommitChanges()
szSite.Stop()
Thread.Sleep(250)
szSite.Start()